# pyside set background image via style sheet not working

Tags: python, stylesheet, pyside

I'm Trying to set the background image (which is located in the same folder as the application) of a QGridLayout widget via pyside to no avail I have looked at all the tuts, docs and forum posts regarding stylesheets' but still i cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        j = 0
        pos =  [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
                (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
                (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3),
                (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3),
                (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3),
                (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]

        grid  = QGridLayout(self)
        items = ["one", "Two", 'Three','four','five']

        for e in items:
            picture = ImageLabel("Book.png", self)
            picture.name = e
            picture.setFixedSize(128,128)
            picture.mousepos = str(picture.pos())
            picture.imageClicked.connect(self.anotherSlot)
            grid.addWidget(picture, pos[j][0], pos[j][1])
            j = j + 1
            picture.setToolTip('This is' + str(e) + ' widget')
            picture.imageHovered.connect(self.Item_Hovered)

        self.setStyleSheet("QGridLayout {background-image: url(./image.jpg) }");


    def anotherSlot(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print "I clicked item " + str(sender.name)

    def Item_Hovered(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print "I'm Hovering over " + str(sender.name)

class ImageLabel(QLabel):

    imageClicked = Signal(str) # can be other types (list, dict, object...)
    imageHovered = Signal(str)
    imageLeave   = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, image, parent=None):
        super(ImageLabel, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.setPixmap(image)
        # self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "from ImageLabel.mousePressEvent()"
        self.imageClicked.emit("Image Clicked")

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print "from ImageLabel.enterEvent()"
        self.imageHovered.emit("Hovering")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print "from ImageLabel.leaveEvent()"
        self.imageLeave.emit("Hovering No More")


a = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if it works you'll not get the expected result, the only way I achieve correct background paint is overriding paintEvent

```
tile = QtGui.QPixmap("x.png")

def paintEvent(self, pe):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.drawTiledPixmap(self.rect(), tile)
    super(Console, self).paintEvent(pe)
```

Console is my class `class Console(QtGui.QMainWindow):`
The example applies to the whole window.

I'm not sure the painter constructor can be moved away from `paintEvent`

**Update**: looks like `QPainter` needs to be created on each `paintEvent`

I've found an easiest way without override the `paintEvent`

```
palette = QtGui.QPalette()
palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, tile)
self.setPalette(palette)
```

Comment: thanks sherpya that helped took a little while to wrap my head around it but i got it working. what confused me with your explanation was self.tile which on realisation was the actual pix-map image variable

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Qt Stylesheet Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html), it lists the widgets that can be customized using stylesheets.

QGridLayout inherits from QLayout, QLayoutItem, and QObject.  According to the reference, none of those are are able to be styled using stylesheets.

Rather than customizing the paintEvent handler, simply try putting your layout inside of a QFrame. QFrame supports the CSS box model, thus you can use the background-image property on the QFrame.

Answer (score 0):

as sherpya explains above the easiest way to achieve the background image of a widget/window is to customise the paintEvent handler of the particular widget in question so here's the code based on the above explanation that finally worked.

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    self.tile= QPixmap("bookshelf.png")
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.drawTiledPixmap(self.rect(), self.tile)
    super(Main, self).paintEvent(event)
```

what sherpyas code didnt explain (which actually helped me understand the paintEvent) was that self.tile variable contains the actual pixmap image which if referenced within the paint variable itself.

```
self.tile= QPixmap("bookshelf.png")
```

will draw the image the background of the widget/window where the stylesheet creates errors!